# leer un archivo cvs y convertir a numeros en r

Tags: r, csv

```
x <- read.csv(file= "Datos.csv", header = TRUE)
```

resultado

```
> x
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
> y<- c(x)
```

Resultado

```
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 4 5 6
```

deseo obtener un vector numérico

Comment: Bienvenido David Cademartori a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: `read.csv()` simplemente esta leyendo un archivo y devolviendo un `data.frame` con dos columnas, que parecen ser numéricas. ¿Que es lo que buscas?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Entendi el concepto